# Combining Either's in Vavr?

Tags: java, functional-programming, vavr

I have a couple of [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) [Either](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_either)'s and I want to invoke a function with the `Right` value for each of these Either's. For example:

```java
Either<MyError, String> either1 = ..
Either<MyError, String> either2 = ..
Either<MyError, String> either3 = ..

Either<MyError, String>> methodRequiringAllInputs(String, String, String) { 
..
}
```

I could of course do something like this:

```java
either1.flatMap { value1 ->
    either2.flatMap { value2 ->
        either3.flatMap { value3 ->
            methodRequiringAllInputs(value1, value2, value3);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is very ugly. In other languages you could just use something like do-notation or for comprehensions to flatten out the structure. I know that Vavr has the concept of a [Validation](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_validation) which is an applicative functor that allows you to do:

```java
Validation<MyError, String> validation1 = ..
Validation<MyError, String> validation2 = ..
Validation<MyError, String> validation3 = ..

Validation.combine(validation1, validation2, validation3)
          .ap((validationValue1,validationValue2,validationValue3) -> .. );
```

which is much nicer.

My question is if something similar exists in Vavr for Either's to avoid the nested `flatMap` structure? Note that I *don't* want to convert the `Either`'s to `Validation`'s.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a *for comprehension* construct in vavr that you could use for your use case. It helps you transform multiple `Iterable`, `Option`, `Try`, `Future` or `List` instances to another `Iterator`, `Option`, `Try`, `Future` or `List` instance respectively, by combining them (as rows of their cartesian product) into result values.

In your case, `Either` being an `Iterable` on the *right* value, you can use the `For` construct for `Iterable`s to construct a `Tuple3` of the `String` right values, and iterate over the resulting `Iterator` by invoking your side-effecting code, or mapping/transforming them in whatever way you want. You will have a *rich* vavr `Iterator`, so that's a lot more flexible than a simple JDK `Iterator`.

```
import static io.vavr.API.For;

For(either1, either2, either3)
    .yield(Tuple::of)
    .forEach(t -> methodRequiringAllInputs(t._1, t._2, t._3));
```

One small note though: in the above case, the result from the `yield` is a lazily evaluated `Iterator`. That means you'll need to iterate over it in the end in order to have the effects executed, so the `forEach` part is essential. You cannot move the side-effecting code into the `yield` part and skip the `forEach`, as the `yield` part will only be (lazily) executed when the resulting `Iterator` is being iterated over.