# Writing readable code using vavr Either in Kotlin while performing sequential operations

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, either, vavr

I have following piece of code written in Kotlin using vavr. The function performs a chain of operations one by one and if one of them fails, it returns Error. If all operations succeed, it returns SuccessObject. Left is assumed to be error and right the success flow. However, this function is difficult to read because of all the .map() constructs. Is there a way to simplify this code to make it more readable?

```
private fun performOperation(param: String): Either<Error, SuccessObject> {
  return performValidation(param)
    .map {
      initiateOperation(param)
        .map { result ->
          oneMoreValidation(param, result.property)
            .map { validationResult ->
              updateDatabase(param, validationResult, result)
            }
            .getOrElseGet { error -> left(error) }
        }
        .getOrElseGet { error -> left(error) }
    }
    .getOrElseGet { error -> left(error) }   
}

private fun performValidation(param: String): Either<Error, ValidationResponse> {}
private fun initiateOperation(param: String): Either<Error, InitOperationResponse> {}
private fun oneMoreValidation(param: String, property: String): Either<Error, OneMoreValidationResponse> {}
private fun updateDatabase(param: String, property: String, result: InitOperationResponse): Either<Error, SuccessObject> {}
```

I looked into [combining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661039/combining-eithers-in-vavr), [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665703/chaining-functions-that-return-vavr-either) Eithers. But none of them seems to simplify the code to make more readable. I also looked into this [blog](https://medium.com/polarizertech/refactoring-if-else-either-and-flatmap-4f1ca9076664) on Railway Oriented Programming. But all the methods accept the same param there. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
As pointed out by VLAZ and Hinse, `.flatMap()` could mitigate this. The function becomes:

```
private fun performOperation(param: String): Either<Error, SuccessObject> {
  return performValidation(param)
    .flatMap {
      initiateOperation(param)
        .flatMap { result ->
          oneMoreValidation(param, result.property)
            .flatMap { validationResult ->
              updateDatabase(param, validationResult, result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is definitely an improvement. But the function still has clutter in terms of indentation and repeated use of `.flatMap()`. So is this the accepted way of implementing functions or can it still be improved?

Comment: Is there not a `,flatMap()` (or equivalent) for `Either`?

Comment: yep, Vavr's Either has a `flatMap` which would definitely remove part of the bloat in the code. If you'd replace the `map` calls with `flatMap` you could remove all the `getOrElseGet` calls.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But that just removes half of the code which is not related to what this function does. If there are many operations to perform, it becomes an indented list of `.flatMap()` functions.

Comment: Vavr was created specifically for java, it works very well with Kotlin but it is rather recommended to use Arrow in Kotlin instead of Vavr, I think. But in your case it is rather a problem of organization of your code. In FP we will tend to break down our treatments into specific methods. So I think it will be easier to put the processing of your first flatMap in a specific method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting your maps, you can do one after the other like so:

```kotlin
private fun performOperation(param: String): Either<Error, SuccessObject> {
  return performValidation(param)
    .flatMap {
      initiateOperation(param)
    }
    .flatMap { result ->
      oneMoreValidation(param, result.property)
    }
    .flatMap { validationResult ->
      updateDatabase(param, validationResult, result)
    }
}
```